# help with mariadb after update trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trigger, insert

I have a table that is shared among 7 other tables and I want to synchronize a new part is added to the parts table. new rows are created in each of the 7 other tables, using the part_id from the insertion.  The wip_id is an int and id that is the result of the insertion to the master_wip table is also an int.

Ive tried using the following:

```
create or replace trigger wip_to_flt
after insert on master_wip for each row
begin
    insert into flt_processing_brd (wip_id) value(new.id);
    insert into phsandt (wip_id) value(new.id);
    insert into label_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
    insert into le_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
    insert into elrod_brd (wip_id) value(new.id);
    insert into ncr_pr_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
    insert into ir_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
end;
```

I get the following error:

```
    -> after insert on master_wip for each row
    -> begin
    ->     insert into flt_processing_board (wip_id) value(NEW.id);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
MariaDB [wip]>     insert into phsandt (wip_id) value(new.id);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'new.id' in 'field list'
MariaDB [wip]>     insert into label_board (wip_id) value (new.id);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'new.id' in 'field list'
MariaDB [wip]>     insert into le_board (wip_id) value (new.id);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'new.id' in 'field list'
MariaDB [wip]>     insert into elrod_board (wip_id) value(new.id);
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'wip.elrod_board' doesn't exist
MariaDB [wip]>     insert into ncr_pr_board (wip_id) value (new.id);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'new.id' in 'field list'
MariaDB [wip]>     insert into ir_board (wip_id) value (new.id);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'new.id' in 'field list'
MariaDB [wip]> end;
```

When I do, it complains about the new keyword in the declaration and id is a relevant column in the master_wip table.  What am I missing?

Comment: Please post your schema as well.

Comment: Can you update your post with the error you're getting?

Comment: Trigger text is correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/6q-5mNga Provide **complete** and **unchanged** error message text. Maybe the error is your client's pre-parser "service"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Change the delimiter from semicolon `;` to double dollar sign `$$`

```
DELIMITER $$

drop trigger if exists wip_to_flt $$
create trigger wip_to_flt
after insert on master_wip for each row
begin
    insert into flt_processing_brd (wip_id) value(new.id);
    insert into phsandt (wip_id) value(new.id);
    insert into label_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
    insert into le_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
    insert into elrod_brd (wip_id) value(new.id);
    insert into ncr_pr_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
    insert into ir_brd (wip_id) value (new.id);
end $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The semicolons inside the begin/end block are OK

Comment: @new2code Please let me know if this worked